# I have to validate availability of jvms by hitting a server url

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working on an automation of hitting several server urls (that are hit manually now one by one) in a single click and in response I'll be getting a login page for each response, that meant jvm is up and running.

The issue is the jvm could take upto 5 minutes to response, and there are as many as 10 urls so the total time taken on checking the response code would take maximum of 50 minutes (worst case - all jvms are down).

So, I have to work on two things -
That the server urls that we are going to hit, in a single click should happen synchronously (that will bring down drastically the overall response time from 50 minutes to 5-6 minutes). I have used a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager method -

```
`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();


            static int statusCode;

        // Here the servers string array have URLs defined in JSP Page -
<!-- <form name="input" action="welcome"  method="get">
            <input type="checkbox" name="server" value="http://hc.apache.org/" checked>Apache HC Home Page<br>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="server" value="http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/" checked>HttpCore<br>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="server" value="https://gmail.com" checked>Gmail<br>  -->
       // create a thread for each URI
        public void synchronizeUrls(String[] servers) throws InterruptedException
        {
        GetThread[] threads = new GetThread[servers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(servers[i]);
            threads[i] = new GetThread(httpClient, httpget);
        }


        // start the threads
        for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
            threads[j].start();
        }

        // join the threads
        for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
            threads[j].join();
        }
        }




        static class GetThread extends Thread {

            private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
            private final HttpContext context;
            private final HttpGet httpget;

            public GetThread(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, HttpGet httpget) {
                this.httpClient = httpClient;
                this.context = HttpClientContext.create();
                this.httpget = httpget;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(
                            httpget, context);

                    final HttpClientConnectionManager connMgr = null;
                    try {
                    //    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                        System.out.println(statusCode);

                    }
                }   // Handle protocol errors
                    catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Handle I/O errors
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                } 
            }`
```

and
the other thing is that if we are not getting response from any of the url in a time interval of 5 minutes duration, we are treating that case as jvm is down.
I am not sure, how to implement the second set of my requirement and it would be very helpful if someone can assist me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. The way I'd do it is as follows.

What you want to do is:

1. Run threads parallely and capture result of each
2. After 5 mins, check if they are still running. The ones still running indicate that corresponding jvm is down

For step 1, add `statusCode` to `GetThread`. [You are already setting `statusCode` in `run()`.]

```
private StatusCode statusCode;
public StatusCode getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}
```

For step 2, add this code after the block of starting threads:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
                if(threads[j].getStatusCode().equals(OK)) {
                    //threads[j]'s jvm is up
                } else {
                    //threads[j]'s jvm is down
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    5 * 60 * 1000
);
```